# Twitter4j: Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect

Tags: java, authentication, twitter, twitter4j

I am creating a program to search for tweets having a given keyword using Twitter4j API but I am getting the error during authentication:

```
Exception in thread "main" 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
message - Invalid or expired token.
code - 89

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=506c3b98 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1136695b
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[506c3b98-1136695b], statusCode=401, message=Invalid or expired token., code=89, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.4}
```

I verified all the tokens in my *twitter4j.properties* file and tried all the possible solutions mentioned in SO site but they didn't worked for me. I have spent hours to correct the error but am still clueless what's the problem ?

Comment: Can you post the code of your authetication process?

Comment: I am not using ConfigurationBuilder code for authentication,I only made twitter4j.properties file which twitter4j library will you to authenticate.

Comment: What are you store into _twitter4j.properties_ file? As I know, you need to have **consumerKey** and **consumerSecret** and then using it you can request **OAuthRequestToken**. Looks like you are using wrong token.

Comment: I am using oauth.consumerKey, oauth.consumerSecret, oauth.accessToken, oauth.accessTokenSecret . I verified all of them many times. What should I place in callback URL in twitter apps?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem was, I added all the jars which comes with Twitter4j API in my build path library. I just removed all other jars except `twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar`and it worked.